# Is it possible to store multiple multidimensional arrays in a single array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have many 3x3 arrays that I would like to store together in a single array. is this possible? if so, how would I got about doing it?

Comment: Yes, it's another dimension in the array.  Multiple instances of a _n_-dimensional array stored together are a _n+1_-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
int size = // ...
int[][][] array3d = new int[size][][];

// let's now store the arrays:
arrays3d[0] = some2darray;
// ...
```